# HTML5 Canvas game file system

Tags: html, google-chrome, file-io

I'm currently working on an html5 game using javascript and heavy use of the canvas element.

As of right now the game is stored on my local hard drive and I'm running it on google chrome locally, no webserver, as of now at least. I am looking for a way to read and maybe possibly write plain text files within the local folder of the game.

I would be fine with just being able to read text files because I can just use web storage to store anything I want into the browser.  The text files would be used to store levels and then read by javascript and interpreted as the tiles that is shown on screen.  These text files are going to be staying in the same folder as the website is at all times.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use WebStorage instead, as it's designed for things like you describe.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/

Note that often when you start using features like this, because of strict security on browsers you will probably need to run your own local HTTP server to make use of these things.

Comment: I really need to be able to store these things into a file though, webstorage is ok for storing save data and things of that nature but not for storing level data for tile coordinates that could possibly be updated or even worked on in the future.